# TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined at jira.issue.get

Tags: node.js, jira, jira-rest-api

I am trying to get data from a jira server and need to show that data on a  webpage/console but i am getting a type error at jira.get if there is another jira api which i can use rather than this easily please let me know

Thanks in advance

My Nodejs code is below

```
    var express=require("express");
        var app=express();
        var mysql=require("mysql");
        var request = require('request');
        var passport = require('passport')
        var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
        var bodyParser     =        require("body-parser");
        var JiraApi = require('jira').JiraApi;

        app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
       app.get('/service',function(req,res){
    var id = req.query.name; 
    res.send(id);
    console.log(id); 
      var options = {
    config: {
        "username": "username",
        "passowrd": "password",
        "host": "example.com"+id
    },
    issueIdOrKey: id
};

    jira.issue.get(options, function(response) {
    res.end(JSON.stringify(response));
});
  });
        console.log('running');
        app.listen(8082);
```

Comment: What documentation are you reading? It seems that there is no method called "get", it is probably called something else.

Comment: Sorry it is jira.issue.get

Comment: i have edited the query please see again

Comment: @ Josef Engelfrost please see again i have edited my code also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jira.issue.get` is throwing a `TypeError` because `jira.issue` is not defined. This is nothing special to Jira and can be demonstrated like so:

```
$ node
> x = {};
{}
> x.a
undefined
> x.a.b()
TypeError: Cannot call method 'b' of undefined
at repl:1:6
at REPLServer.self.eval (repl.js:110:21)
at Interface.<anonymous> (repl.js:239:12)
at Interface.emit (events.js:95:17)
at Interface._onLine (readline.js:203:10)
at Interface._line (readline.js:532:8)
at Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:761:14)
at ReadStream.onkeypress (readline.js:100:10)
at ReadStream.emit (events.js:98:17)
at emitKey (readline.js:1096:12)
```

From the [jira npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jira) it looks like you need to instantiate an instance of the JiraApi 'class', then use that to find an issue. From the npm example:

```
JiraApi = require('jira').JiraApi;

var jira = new JiraApi('https', config.host, config.port, config.user,      config.password, '2.0.alpha1');
jira.findIssue(issueNumber, function(error, issue) {
  console.log('Status: ' + issue.fields.status.name);
});
```